# Why doesn't the R function in my reprex display the legend?

Tags: r, ggplot2

The following R function is supposed to display two coloured lines, using ggplot, along with a legend. It displays the two lines, but not the legend. Where is my error?

```
library(tidyverse)
MkChrt <- function(df,x_col1,y_col1,x_col2,y_col2,ynam1,ynam2,legName,titl) {
  c0 <- ggplot(df)+
  geom_line(aes(x={{x_col1}},y={{y_col1}},colour=ynam1),linewidth=1.2)+
  geom_line(aes(x={{x_col2}},y={{y_col2}},colour=ynam2),linewidth=1.2)+
  labs(title=titl,x="",y="") +
  scale_colour_manual(name=legName,values=c(ynam1="red",ynam2="blue"))+
  theme(legend.position=c(0.25,0.85),
    legend.key=element_rect(fill="transparent"),
    legend.background=element_rect(fill="transparent"),
    legend.text=element_text(size=14),
    legend.title=element_text(size=16))+
  NULL
  return(c0)
}
LP <- data.frame(Date=seq.Date(as.Date("2023-01-01"),as.Date("2023-10-01"),
  by="quarter"),L1=c(90,92,95,91),L2=c(50,54,59,61))
c0 <- MkChrt(LP,Date,L1,Date,L2,
  "L1","L2","Legend for L1 and L2",
  "Labour productivity"
)
c0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create the named vector explicitly, rather than in the `scale_colour_manual()`.

```
library(tidyverse)
MkChrt <- function(df,x_col1,y_col1,x_col2,y_col2,ynam1,ynam2,legName,titl) {
  
  
  colors = c("red", "blue")
  names(colors) <- c(ynam1, ynam2)
  
  c0 <- ggplot(df)+
    geom_line(aes(x={{x_col1}},y={{y_col1}},color=ynam1),linewidth=1.2)+
    geom_line(aes(x={{x_col2}},y={{y_col2}},color=ynam2),linewidth=1.2)+
    labs(title=titl,x="",y="") +
    scale_colour_manual(name=legName, values= colors)+
    theme(legend.position =c(0.25,0.85),
          legend.key=element_rect(fill="transparent"),
          legend.background=element_rect(fill="transparent"),
          legend.text=element_text(size=14),
          legend.title=element_text(size=16))+
    NULL
  return(c0)
}
LP <- data.frame(Date=seq.Date(as.Date("2023-01-01"),as.Date("2023-10-01"),
                               by="quarter"),L1=c(90,92,95,91),L2=c(50,54,59,61))
c0 <- MkChrt(LP,Date,L1,Date,L2,
             "L1","L2","Legend for L1 and L2",
             "Labour productivity"
)
c0
```